# application.OnTime TimeValue("hh:mm:ss") triggers my macro twice

Tags: vba, excel

I extract data, make amends to these data then send them via email.

`application.OnTime TimeValue("hh:mm:ss")` triggers my macro twice which means I receive 2 emails one right after.

I added multiple application.OnTime lines to send this email every 30 minutes.

Below is the whole code:

```
Sub scheduler()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("14:10:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("14:31:01"), "ddd"
End Sub

Sub ddd()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("14:31:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("15:01:01"), "eee"
End Sub

Sub eee()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("15:01:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("15:31:01"), "fff"
End Sub

Sub fff()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("15:31:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("16:01:01"), "ggg"
End Sub

Sub ggg()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("16:01:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("16:31:01"), "hhh"
End Sub

Sub hhh()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("16:31:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("17:01:01"), "iii"
End Sub

Sub iii()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("17:01:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("17:31:01"), "jjj"
End Sub

Sub jjj()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("17:31:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("18:01:01"), "kkk"
End Sub

Sub kkk()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("18:01:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("18:31:01"), "lll"
End Sub

Sub lll()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("18:31:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("19:01:01"), "mmm"
End Sub

Sub mmm()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("19:01:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("19:31:01"), "nnn"
End Sub

Sub nnn()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("19:31:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("20:01:01"), "ooo"
End Sub

Sub ooo()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("20:01:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("20:31:01"), "ppp"
End Sub

Sub ppp()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("20:31:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("21:01:01"), "qqq"
End Sub

Sub qqq()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("21:01:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("21:31:01"), "rrr"
End Sub

Sub rrr()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("21:31:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("22:01:01"), "sss"
End Sub

Sub sss()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("22:01:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("22:31:01"), "ttt"
End Sub

Sub ttt()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("22:31:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("23:01:01"), "uuu"
End Sub

Sub uuu()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("23:01:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("23:31:01"), "vvv"
End Sub

Sub vvv()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("23:31:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("23:57:01"), "www"
End Sub

Sub www()
    application.OnTime TimeValue("23:57:31"), "myMacro"
    application.OnTime TimeValue("23:59:01"), "scheduler"
End Sub

Sub myMacro()
    Dim path As String
    Dim site As String

    path = "chrome's path"
    site = "https://mysite"

    Shell (path & site)
    application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))

    Const SOME_PATH As String = "downloaded file path"
    Dim file As String
    file = Dir$(SOME_PATH & "JHGK_Responses*" & ".xlsx")

    application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

    If (Len(file) > 0) Then
        Workbooks.Open(SOME_PATH & file).Activate
    End If

    application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    ActiveSheet.Range("A4:BC600").Copy
    Windows("my macro's sheet.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    [L:L].Select
    With Selection
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Range("A3").Select

    application.CutCopyMode = False
    application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:50"))
    Workbooks(file).Activate
    application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

    With New FileSystemObject
        If .FileExists(SOME_PATH & file) Then
            .DeleteFile SOME_PATH & file
        End If
    End With

    Windows("my marco's sheet.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("Pivots").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    Worksheets("Email").Activate
    application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    Dim EmailSubject As String
    Dim SendTo As String
    Dim EmailBody As String
    Dim ccTo As String
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Sheets("Email").Range("A1:E72")

    r.Copy

    EmailSubject = "whatever at " & Format(Time, "hh:mm")
    SendTo = Range("Q10")
    ccTo = Range("Q10")

    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.application
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("outlook.Application")
    Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set outMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With outMail
        .Subject = EmailSubject
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "mailboxname"
        .To = SendTo
        .CC = ccTo
        .body = EmailBody
        .display

        outMail.display
        Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
        Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

        'Paste as Picture
        'wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture

        'paste as Table (remove the comma)
        wordDoc.Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False
        .send
    End With
    Set outlookApp = Nothing
    Set outMail = Nothing

    Windows("my macro's sheet.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Raw").Select
    Range("A3:BC900").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A3").Select
End Sub
```

I have so many subs to trigger myMacro using the application.OnTime method then the other line to trigger the next sub going to the second last sub to loop from the beginning.

Windows Task Scheduler is not an option due to my corporate security policy.

Comment: @Kostas K. can you help please?

Comment: Do you really need `myMacro` to run at those odd times, or would you be happy to just run it every half hour between 2pm and midnight?  (i.e. at 14:00, 14:30, 15:00, ..., 23:30, 24:00)  If you were happy to use a regular interval, you would only need one macro to do all the scheduling.

Comment: @YowE3K I know what you mean buddy. I actually wanted the times above and I got it resolved thanks

Comment: Even if you do want to keep the weird times, at least consider moving all the `Application.OnTime` statements for `myMacro` into the one `scheduler` routine (just have that procedure invoke all 21 events), and also have `scheduler` schedule itself for the next day.  There's no real need for all those `ddd`, `eee`. etc procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have called `scheduler` twice in the same Excel session, e.g. while debugging. Restart Excel and make sure `scheduler` is called only once.

Fun fact: if you call `scheduler`, then close the workbook while leaving Excel open, Excel will re-open the workbook at the scheduled time and run the macro. If, in the meantime, you've opened your workbook manually and called `scheduler`, myMacro will launch twice.

Comment: OMG is it that simple? Thanks buddy, it seems about right. I restarted the sheet and ran the macro once and it is working. Seems like this fun fact is kinda serious too lol. Thanks again